# Can't create unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift

So, this is is my code.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
//MARK: PROPERTIES

    @IBOutlet weak var jotTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    /*
    This value is either passed by `MealTableViewController` in `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`
    or constructed as part of adding a new meal.
    */
    var jot: String?



//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
       jotTextField.text = textField.text
    }

//MARK: Navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if saveButton === sender {
            var jot = jotTextField.text ?? ""
            jot = String(jotTextField)
        }

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
        jotTextField.delegate = self


    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func unwindToJotList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? FirstViewController, jot = sourceViewController.jot {
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: jot.count, inSection: 0)
             jot.append(jot)
              JotTableViewCell.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)


        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to create an unwind segue, however, I get errors on these lines:

```
let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: jot.count, inSection: 0)
jot.append(jot)
JotTableViewCell.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
```

First line's error:

> 'count' is unavailable

Second line's error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'jot' is a let constant

It's not a let constant. I declared it as a variable ('var').

Third line's error:

> Type 'jotTableViewCell' has no member 'insertRowsAtIndexPaths'

Please help me. I am very new to the Swift programming language, you could say I'm a noob/novice. This probably seems like a very simple fix for an experienced programmer, not so much me. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but jot's type is a String and Strings do not have a property "count." You might try `jot.characters.count` if you want the number of characters jot has.

In the line:

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? FirstViewController, jot = sourceViewController.jot
```

You have a comma separated declaration meaning it the same as saying

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? FirstViewController {
    if let jot = sourceViewController.jot {

    }
}
```

So you are declaring it as a constant. For more about declaring variables in swift see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

You should call insertRowsAtIndexPaths on an instance of a UITableView not as a class method of a subclass of UITableViewCell as you seem to be doing. For example:

```
self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough - this unwind segue is so that when a button is tapped, it goes back to the original screen, where it will then add what had just been typed to a table view.